# Check if a string is interleaving of two other given strings using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I want to check if s3 is an organized combination of s1 and s2. so I wrote this:

```
def organized_comp(s1,s2,s3):
    l1, l2, l3 = len(s1), len(s2),len(s3)
    if (l1 == 0 and l2 == 0 and l3 ==0):
        return True
    if (l1 == 0 and s2 == s3) or (l2 == 0 and s1 == s3):
        return True
    if (l3 != (l1 +l2)) or (l3 == 0 and (l1 > 0 or l2 > 0)):
        return False    
    if s1 and s1[0] == s3[0]:
        return True and organized_comp(s1[1:], s2, s3[1:])
    if s2 and s2[0] == s3[0]:
        return True and organized_comp(s1, s2[1:], s3[1:])
```

> when I send : s1 = "ABZ" , s2 = "ABAXZ", s3 = "ABAXABZZ"  it returns
> False and it needs to return True. I think I know the problem -
> because s1[0] = s2[0] and it always start with s1 (If I send  s2 =
> "ABZ" , s1 = "ABAXZ" it works).

how I can correct it?

Comment: to check true yuo need to check if all character of s1 are in s2+s3 or not

Comment: why do I have to do this? I need to check if s3 is a combination of s1 and s2

Comment: if all character in s1 are present in list of all character of s2 and s3  then you can tell whether it is true or not easily

Comment: Bit of a mess but something like this might work? `s1 in s3 and s3.replace(s1, '', 1) == s2 or s2 in s3 and s3.replace(s2, '', 1) == s1`

Comment: `def organized_comp(s1,s2,s3): return sorted(s1  + s2) == sorted(s3)`. I don't think you need anything else, thus you can replace the function call with just this one liner: `sorted(s1  + s2) == sorted(s3)`. Unless I misunderstood your exact requirements (I'm not sure what you mean by "organized combination". I've simply gone for "s3 is some complete combination of s1 and s2"). It's also unclear why you want/need recursion.

Comment: we cant use replace, and we have to do it with recursion

Comment: Ok. You may want to add to your question that this is an assignment, that is requires recursion and no replacement. Otherwise, there may be more people suggestion completely different solutions.

Comment: @KellyBundy that wont be recursive solution as OP asked

Comment: @sahasrara62 Right, you could implement it recursively, but it still wouldn't be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis of the issue is correct: if `s1[0] == s2[0]`, then you don't know which character should be used. So, you should try both possibilities, and return True if at least one of them works.

This can be accomplished with logical operator `or`.

Also note that your "if forest" was missing a case where it should return False: when `l1 + l2 == l3` but `s3[0] not in (s1[0], s2[0])`. In python, as opposed to almost every other programming language, if a `return` is missing in a function, python doesn't crash and the function silently returns `None` as if there had been an explicit `return None`. So, the way you wrote it, `organized_comp('a', 'b', 'c')` would return `None` instead of `False`.

Some of your conditions were a bit redundant, for instance the two following conditions would be equivalent:

```py
(l3 != (l1 +l2)) or (l3 == 0 and (l1 > 0 or l2 > 0))
(l3 != (l1 +l2)) # if the second part was True, then the first part would be True anyway
```

Here is a proposed fix:

```py
def organized_comp(s1,s2,s3):
    l1, l2, l3 = len(s1), len(s2),len(s3)
    return (l3 == l1 + l2) and (
        (l3 == 0) or
        (l1 > 0 and s3[0] == s1[0] and organized_comp(s1[1:], s2, s3[1:])) or
        (l2 > 0 and s3[0] == s2[0] and organized_comp(s1, s2[1:], s3[1:]))
    )
```